# Constructing set with maximal independent subset

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, algorithms

What is the minimal $m$ such that there exists a set $A = \{a_1,...a_n\}$ of vectors : $a_i \in \{0,1\}^m$ ($n$ is given) such that every subset of vectors of size $k$ is independent, but only with scalars $\alpha_i = \{-1,0,1\}$? What if we also require that $||a_i||_0 = s$? 
Is there a way to find such a set?

Comment: are you working over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Edited, basically an answer over $\mathbb{R}$ would be ok, but I am interested in the case where all the coefficients of the linear combination can only be $-1,1,0$

Comment: Take $a_i=e_i$, where $e_i$ is the standard vector basis.